# CSS Boot strap navbar scrolling creating bullet point instead of a right nabber item

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I add a navbar with bootstrap. But it seems that it consider each item as a bullet point instead of creating a navbar with a dropdown list in nabber if the user is admin...if not I should have a navbar.

I don't understand where is my error. My style, CSS is empty...Only using bootstrap

thanks for help:

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top topnav" role="navigation">
        <div class="container topnav">
          <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand topnav" href="{{ url_for('home.homepage') }}">Project</a>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <li class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}

                          {% if current_user.is_admin %}
                              <li class="nav-item dropdown">

                                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                                     <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url_for('home.admin_dashboard') }}">Dashboard</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url_for('admin.list_departments') }}">Departments</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url_for('admin.list_roles') }}">Roles</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url_for('admin.list_employees') }}">Users</a>
                                    </div>


                              {% else %}
                                <li><a href="{{ url_for('home.dashboard') }}">Dashboard</a></li>
                          {% endif %}
                          <li><a class="nav-item" href="{{ url_for('auth.logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
                          <li><a><i class="nav-item" class="fa fa-user"></i>  Hi, {{ current_user.username }}!</a></li>
                    {% else %}
                          <li><a class="nav-item" href="{{ url_for('home.homepage') }}">Home</a></li>
                          <li><a class="nav-item" href="{{ url_for('auth.register') }}">Register</a></li>
                          <li><a class="nav-item" href="{{ url_for('auth.login') }}">Login</a></li>
                    {% endif %}
              </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

this is result I have. I don t understand why there is bullet point and why it is not on right side

[image]

Comment: please put your code in the snippet

Comment: what do you mean? I put code in my demand?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

The below snippet should work for you...

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <!-- Links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav">

      <li><a href="{{ url_for('home.dashboard') }}">Dashboard</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-item" href="{{ url_for('auth.logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
      <li><a><i class="nav-item" class="fa fa-user"></i>  Hi, {{ current_user.username }}!</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-item" href="{{ url_for('home.homepage') }}">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-item" href="{{ url_for('auth.register') }}">Register</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-item" href="{{ url_for('auth.login') }}">Login</a></li>
      <!-- Dropdown -->
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Dropdown link
      </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url_for('home.admin_dashboard') }}">Dashboard</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url_for('admin.list_departments') }}">Departments</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url_for('admin.list_roles') }}">Roles</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url_for('admin.list_employees') }}">Users</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<br>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).</p>
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
  <p>Tip: You can also remove the .navbar-expand-md class to ALWAYS hide navbar links and display the toggler button.</p>
</div>
```